# Is there a way to import certificate setup in POSTMAN?

Tags: import, postman, certificate

I have my POSTMAN set-up on one machine with certificates for various servers / urls and ports.  I need to set-up POSTMAN with certificates for the same servers / ports on a second machine.

I have copied the cert and key in the same path on the second machine.

At the moment, the only way I know to set-up the certificates on the second machine is to manually do the same process that I did on the original machine for each server and port.

I was wondering if there is a way to export and import these definitions / set-ups in POSTMAN.